# Jira and Confluence remote issue No route to host

Tags: jira, confluence

I have Jira Core (Software) and Confluence installed on same server. They are connected via application link. Problem is when i adding link to confluence into jira issue it says that page is failed to load.
And there is log:

*/var/atlassian/application-data/jira/log/atlassian-jira.log*

```
Failed to load Confluence Page from remote server Caused by: com.atlassian.sal.api.net.ResponseException: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
```

any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a DNS (well, name resolution) error. Make sure they can resolve each other's host names properly - maybe they are not set to use FQDN? Or using localhost instead of hostname? Is the hostname itself resolvable?

What's the URL you are giving them to talk to each other?

I see this on my servers in AWS when they can't resolve their $HOSTNAME via DNS, Tomcat wants to be able to resolve itself in any possible name.